# WURFL redirects facebook robot

Tags: facebook, wordpress, mobile, wurfl

I have WURFL on my page for redirecting mobile devices to mobile version of site. PCs are redirected to wordpress.
Unfortunately when i try to post link from my wordpress page on facebook it's generating image for link from mobile version, also link stands to be mobile version, rather than concrete post on worpress. 
After clicking submit on facebook it redirects correctly to full version of page, but still the icon should be generated from full version page (same as link title).
How avoid redirecting to mobile version, when facebook services are sending request?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using different detection software. I'm working on an Open Source C implementation of [51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi?CATReferrer=1765)'s device detection solution at the moment. They've got links to open source PHP, ASP and Java solutions on there as well. It's pretty easy to set up and get working on your site.